# Is it possible to print to a specific printer and tray from code?

Tags: printing, .net-4.0

I have an application that creates two reports. The first report is created and shown in a ReportViewer window, when the user clicks the next button (custom button), the second report is shown in a different ReportViewer window.

Within each ReportViewer window, the user can click print and see a print dialog window and print the report.

I would like to have them click print in the first ReportViewer window and the report print to a specific tray on a specific printer. When they click print on the second ReportViewer window, I would like it to print to a different tray on the same printer. I do not want to show them the print dialog.

Is this possible using the 4.0 .Net Framework or some 3rd party component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

For example.  Crystal Reports objects have printer options that include:

```
        objReport.DefaultPrinterDomain = ""
        objReport.DefaultPrinterName = ""
        objReport.DefaultPrinterTray = ""
        objReport.DefaultPrinterIP = ""
        objReport.DefaultAutoPrint = 0
```

I'm not as familiar with other reporting software or with the specific .net framework items that may do this iself.  But if crystal can do it i'm sure there are other ways to do it as well.